# PHP mail() function - postfix

Tags: linux, email, nginx, debian, postfix-mta

I have a problem with postfix configuration. My server is running on Debian 8. I've got nginx installed here. PHP version: 5.6 (PHP5-FPM service)

I've installed postfix and mailutils by commands:

```
apt-get install postfix
apt-get install mailutils
```

phpinfo() returns:

```
sendmail_from test@bociuch.pl
sendmail_path /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
SMTP localhost
smtp_port 25
```

Simple PHP script:

```
mail('test@email.com', 'test', 'test');
```

Mail function returns true but emails aren't sent to others.

What might be the reason for this issue? Has anyone had this kind of problem? Where should I find the errors? Thanks in advance!

Recent logs (/var/log/mail.log):

```
Apr 18 13:50:20 bociuch sendmail[12748]: u3IHoKfU012748: to=dominikg@infobuzer.pl, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30095, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (u3IHoKbp012749 Message accepted for delivery)
Apr 18 13:50:20 bociuch sm-mta[12751]: STARTTLS=client, relay=infobuzer.nazwa.pl., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits=256/256
Apr 18 13:50:20 bociuch sm-mta[12751]: u3IHoKbp012749: to=<dominikg@infobuzer.pl>, ctladdr=<www-data@bociuch.pl> (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120349, relay=infobuzer.nazwa.pl. [85.128.177.26], dsn=5.7.1, stat=User unknown
Apr 18 13:50:21 bociuch sm-mta[12751]: u3IHoKbp012749: u3IHoLbp012751: DSN: User unknown
Apr 18 13:50:22 bociuch sm-mta[12751]: u3IHoLbp012751: to=<www-data@bociuch.pl>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Apr 18 14:05:14 bociuch postfix/master[13234]: fatal: bind 0.0.0.0 port 25: Address already in use
Apr 18 14:05:32 bociuch postfix/postdrop[13249]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Apr 18 14:28:40 bociuch postfix/postdrop[13368]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Apr 18 14:29:01 bociuch postfix/postdrop[13371]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
Apr 18 15:03:32 bociuch postfix/postdrop[13677]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try to run following commands before installing postfix sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/mailname string bociuch" 
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type string 'Internet Site'"

Comment: Also show us your /var/log/mail.log

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I got an alert: Can't open debconf-set-selections: No such file or directory at /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections line 114.

Comment: I don't have access to debian comp right now. But somewhere in /usr/local/postfix or so should exists configuration file for internet site, you need to copy it into /etc/postfix with name main.conf or anyway check this file. It should be commented well enough.

Comment: Well your logs tell following you have installed other mailer (sendmail probably) and it is works. But user dominikg@infobuzer.pl doesn't exist in infobuzer domain.

Comment: This means you do not need to install postfix.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because php 5.6 does not have the correct sendmail_path fot postfix.
Y have changed in php.ini that line

```
sendmail_path = "sendmail -tif from@mydomine.com"
```

And then restart apache (or nginx)

```
service php5.6-fpm restart
```

And the postfix server.

```
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

mail() in php should work now